# link2sd app size incorect

Tags: link2sd

Hi I was wondering someone here had a solution to my problem. I have rooted my tablet, created a ext4 partition and installed link2sd. I did this because I kept running out of space. The problem I am having is that the app size is much larger in application manager then in link2sd. For example I had the walking dead game installed which shows as1.25 gigs in app manager however only about 35 mb in link2nd so when I create the link it only saves me 35mb. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is more to an app besides the application itself. The data for the application may not be moved to the sdcard. Or another example could be apps that download additional data from the play store after installing. So the "base application" might be 35mb, but the additional data may be 1gb. That additional data may not be able to be moved to the sdcard.